# SwiftUI - Make content below a List scrollable as the List scrolling progresses

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list with many elements and two buttons below the list. What I want to achieve is to show the buttons after the user scrolls to the (almost) end of the list. Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let numbers = [1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 43, 42, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 765, 423, 5345, 5345, 345, 4, 8, 21]
        
        List {
            ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                Text(number.description)
            }
        }
        ButtonsStack()
        
    }
}

struct ButtonsStack: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            })
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button2")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This results in buttons being fixed at the bottom (showing all the time):

[fixedButtons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MinBL.png)

If I move the  `ButtonsStack()` inside the `List`, than the buttons will be put as a row of the List which is also not what I want:

[buttonsInsideAList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxtH4.png)

So what I would like to have is buttons as on the first picture, but showing up first when the user scrolls to the bottom of the list. How can I achieve it ? I tried putting everything in a ScrollView but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if the user has scrolled the list to the end, and condition the appearance of the buttons to that.
The easiest way is to check when the last line appears on the screen (`onAppear`) :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var thisIsTheEnd = false
    var body: some View {
        let numbers = [1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 43, 42, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 765, 423, 5345, 5345, 345, 4, 8, 21]
        
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(numbers.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    if index == numbers.count - 1 {
                        Text(numbers[index].description)
                            .onAppear {
                                thisIsTheEnd = true
                            }
                    } else {
                        Text(numbers[index].description)
                    }
                }
            }
            if thisIsTheEnd {
                ButtonsStack()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, this goes in the right direction ! One more thing left is, we need a way to hide the ButtonsStack() again when I scroll to the beginning of the table, here it remains fixed

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you're after is setting a `footer` to the list. In that case, I think this should do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let numbers = [1, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 43, 42, 4, 7, 3, 7, 3, 2, 1, 4, 765, 423, 5345, 5345, 345, 4, 8, 21]
    
        List {
            Section(footer: ButtonsStack()) {
                ForEach(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text(number.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it resulted in having ButtonsStack() as a last row of the table and an another ButtonsStack() fixed below the list. What I want to is to have a ButtonsStack() below the list reached after someone scrolled to the end of the list, not a as a row of the list.